# java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-studio-2.0

I am getting this error again and again
Error:Execution failed for task ':quickScroll:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'. > java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute

I tried using tools:node="merge".

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="49"
    android:versionName="3.5">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <uses-sdk
            tools:node="replace"
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

        <application
            android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.Utils.Common"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />

            <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement -->
            ;
            <service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService" />

            <receiver
                android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
                android:exported="true" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- Now Playing Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.NowPlayingActivity.NowPlayingActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/now_playing"
                android:launchMode="singleTask" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:scheme="content" />
                    <data android:host="media" />
                    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <!-- Equalizer Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.EqualizerActivity.EqualizerActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/equalizer" >
            </activity>

            <!-- Launcher Activity -->

            <activity android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.LauncherActivity.LauncherActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <!-- Welcome Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.WelcomeActivity.WelcomeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>

            <!-- Main Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.MainActivity.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            </activity>

            <!-- Services -->

            <service android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.Services.AudioPlaybackService" />
            <service android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.Services.AutoFetchAlbumArtService" />
            <service android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.Services.PinGMusicSongsService" />

            <service
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.Services.BuildMusicLibraryService"
                android:exported="false" />
            <service
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.Services.DashClockExtensionService"
                android:icon="@drawable/dashclock_icon"
                android:label="@string/app_full_name"
                android:permission="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.permission.READ_EXTENSION_DATA" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.Extension" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="protocolVersion"
                    android:value="2" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="worldReadable"
                    android:value="true" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="description"
                    android:value="@string/dashclock_description" />
            </service>

            <!-- Large Widget -->

            <receiver
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.WidgetProviders.LargeWidgetProvider"
                android:label="ACE Large Widget" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/large_widget_info" />
            </receiver>

            <!-- Blurred Widget -->

            <receiver
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.WidgetProviders.BlurredWidgetProvider"
                android:label="ACE Blurred Album Art Widget" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/blurred_widget_info" />
            </receiver>

            <!-- Album Art Widget -->

            <receiver
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.WidgetProviders.AlbumArtWidgetProvider"
                android:label="ACE Album Art Widget" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/album_art_widget_info" />
            </receiver>

            <!-- Listens for media playback buttons (headphone buttons, bluetooth buttons, etc.) -->

            <receiver android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BroadcastReceivers.HeadsetButtonsReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- Small Widget -->

            <receiver
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.WidgetProviders.SmallWidgetProvider"
                android:label="ACE Small Widget" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/small_widget_info" />
            </receiver>

            <!-- Large widget configuration activity -->

            <activity android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.WidgetProviders.LargeWidgetConfigActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <!-- Small widget configuration activity -->

            <activity android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.WidgetProviders.SmallWidgetConfigActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <!-- Widget/Notification Now Playing Activity Broadcast Receiver -->

            <receiver android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BroadcastReceivers.LaunchNowPlayingReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.LAUNCH_NOW_PLAYING_ACTION" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- Widget/Notification Play/Pause Broadcast Receiver -->

            <receiver android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BroadcastReceivers.PlayPauseBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.PLAY_PAUSE_ACTION" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- Widget/Notification Previous Broadcast Receiver -->

            <receiver android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BroadcastReceivers.PreviousBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.PREVIOUS_ACTION" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- Widget/Notification Next Broadcast Receiver -->

            <receiver android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BroadcastReceivers.NextBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.NEXT_ACTION" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- Stop Service Broadcast Receiver -->

            <receiver android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BroadcastReceivers.StopServiceBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.STOP_SERVICE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- Receiver that gets called when the user changes songs from the Large Widget -->

            <receiver android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BroadcastReceivers.ChangeTrackBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.WIDGET_CHANGE_TRACK" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- Main Settings Activity -->

            <activity android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.SettingsActivity.SettingsActivity" >
            </activity>

            <!-- Dummy activity that launches Fragment dialogs from the Main Settings Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.SettingsActivity.PreferenceDialogLauncherActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppThemeTransparent" >
            </activity>

            <!-- Now Playing Queue Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.NowPlayingQueueActivity.NowPlayingQueueActivity"
                android:label="@string/now_playing_queue" >
            </activity>

            <!-- Blacklist Manager -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BlacklistManagerActivity.BlacklistManagerActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_blacklist_manager" >
            </activity>

            <!-- Music Libraries Editor Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.MusicLibraryEditorActivity.MusicLibraryEditorActivity"
                android:label="@string/music_library_editor" >
            </activity>

            <!-- Music Libraries Editor Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.PlaylistEditorActivity.PlaylistEditorActivity"
                android:label="@string/playlists" >
            </activity>

            <!-- KitKat Fix Activity -->

            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.Services.KitKatFixActivity"
                android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
                android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:stateNotNeeded="true"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BrowserSubListActivity.BrowserSubListActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_browser_sub" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="musicplayer.player.music.audioplayer.musicplayer.BrowserSubGridActivity.BrowserSubGridActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_browsser_sub_grid" >
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

And Manifest file for quickScroll is like

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andraskindler.quickscroll"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="0.8.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

</manifest>
```

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance. I am using Android studio 2.0.0.

Comment: Why not just set the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file? That overrides any library's manifest, or even your own app's manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `tools:node="replace"`, instead, you have to use `tools:overrideLibrary` as mentioned in the [Manifest merging markers docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Markers):

```
<uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="14"
           android:targetSdkVersion="23"
           tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
```

Of course, unless their minSdkVersion is higher than your minSdkVersion (which doesn't seem to be the case here), your app's minSdkVersion will take precedence.

Comment: Sir, i added                                tools:overrideLibrary="com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview, com.mobeta.android.dslv, de.psdev.licensesdialog, com.squareup.picasso, com.andraskindler.quickscroll, com.velocity.view.pager.library, com.velocityviewpagerindicator"     in the manifest. But, now its shows that there is a problem in a Java class which was all ok till now.

Comment: /Users/anuragsingh/AndroidStudioProjects/MusicPlayer/app/src/main/java/musicplayer/player/music/audioplayer/musicplayer/BroadcastReceivers/HeadsetButtonsReceiver.java                                                                    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Certainly after you fix your current problem, you may run into further problems. I'd open new questions for new problems though.